# Is it possible to add one2many inside one2many field in openerp?

Tags: odoo

For example I need to add bom lines inside sale order lines. I have created an on_change function to load the bom lines if the product have bom. It is working fine in GTK, but when I try to add in web client, its not working..

Answer (score 1):

Look at the product screen's Suppliers tab. One product can have many suppliers and each supplier can have many prices. To see the price list, you must enable the extended view for your user account.

Here's a screen shot of the GTK client with the suppliers switched from tree view to form view so you can see both levels.
[image: GTK client]

The web client can't display both levels at the same time. You have to open the supplier in a dialog box, and it shows you the list of prices there.
[image: web client]

Comment: Thank you Don Kirkby...I think my problem was due to the on_change function.When I removed it its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to trigger control to another form based on th onchange of a selection field? the new form is to be linked to the new button of the existing form.